# AngularJS select an empty option when loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and I really need help with this issue.

```js
csApp.controller('expensesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getExpenses = function () {
            $http.post('/Home/ExpensesTableList').then(function (response) {
                $scope.vendorList = response.data.csVendors;
                $scope.list = response.data.csExpenses;
            });
        };
        $scope.getExpenses();
    });

// returned json
{"csExpenses":[{"vendorNo":1}],
 "csVendors":[{"vendorNo":1,"vendorName":"Aliexpress"},{"vendorNo":2,"vendorName":"DHGate"}]}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in list" ng-cloak >
  <td>                                    
    <select ng-model="item.vendorNo" 
            ng-options="vendor.vendorName for vendor in vendorList track by vendor.vendorNo"></select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I run this, it generates option value="?" and always selects the option value="?" I know option value="?" is generated when angular cannot find the right value from the list. But it does have a right value in the list which matches with the binding model value and type (integer).

```html
<option selected="selected" value="?"></option>
<option value="1" label="Aliexpress">Aliexpress</option>
<option value="2" label="DHGate">DHGate</option></select>
```

Can someone please help why it is selecting the value="?" always?

Comment: your `ng-options` is wrong, it is outputting the object and assigning it to `item.vendorNo`;  you probably just want it to output to `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `vendor.vendorNo as vendor.vendorName` inside `ng-options`

```
  <td>
    <select ng-model="item.vendorNo" ng-options="vendor.vendorNo as vendor.vendorName for vendor in vendorList" ng-selected="true"></select>{{item.vendorNo}}
  </td>
```

```js
var csApp = angular.module("app", []);
csApp.controller('expensesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getExpenses = function() {
    //$http.post('/Home/ExpensesTableList').then(function (response) {
    var response = {
      "csExpenses": [{
        "vendorNo": 1
      }],
      "csVendors": [{
        "vendorNo": 1,
        "vendorName": "Aliexpress"
      }, {
        "vendorNo": 2,
        "vendorName": "DHGate"
      }]
    };
    $scope.vendorList = response.csVendors;
    $scope.list = response.csExpenses;
    //});
  };
  $scope.getExpenses();
});

// returned json
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="expensesCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list" ng-cloak>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="item.vendorNo" ng-options="vendor.vendorNo as vendor.vendorName for vendor in vendorList" ng-selected="true"></select>{{item.vendorNo}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this might work, but it's really not necessary, not a proper use for `ng-init`, and doesn't really address the actual problem;  The OP is likely to see the same unexpected values in `selectedItem` as they would have in their original model.

Comment: @Claies I have corrected my answer. Please check the updated answer. I think setting VendorNo as VendorName will suit for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `ng-options` can be quite confusing, but what is happening in your case is that you are actually outputting the *entire object* to the `ng-model`, but your `ng-model` is set up as if you are only outputting one property.

Breaking down the `ng-options` a bit more:

```
vendor.vendorname //sets the text to display in the list
for vendor // sets what gets output for each row
in vendorList // sets what gets iterated
track by vendor.vendorNo //sets the order the list is displayed.
```

There is an `as` clause that allows you to output a specific property, but it is generally not necessary.  Also, `select as` and `track by` are not designed to be used together.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

So based on this, instead of setting `ng-model="item.vendorNo"`, you actually want to set `ng-model="item"`

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var json = {
    "csExpenses": [{
      "vendorNo": 1
    }],
    "csVendors": [{
      "vendorNo": 1,
      "vendorName": "Aliexpress"
    }, {
      "vendorNo": 2,
      "vendorName": "DHGate"
    }]
  }

  $scope.vendorList = json.csVendors;
  $scope.list = json.csExpenses;

  $scope.change = function() {
    console.log($scope.list);
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list" ng-cloak>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="item" ng-change="change()" ng-options="vendor.vendorName for vendor in vendorList track by vendor.vendorNo"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zQPryQvH2zF2YUFFXpU8?p=preview